# How to clean a file, replacing unwanted seperators, operators, string literals

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I'm working on a concordance problem where I must: "Clean the file. For this, remove all string literals (anything enclosed
in double quotes, the second of which is not preceded by an odd number 
of backslashes), remove all // comments, remove all separator characters 
(look these up), and operators (look these up). Do not worry about ".class literals" (we will assume they will not appear in the input file)."

I think I know how the replaceAll() method works, but I don't know what's going to be in the file.  For starters, how would I go about removing all string literals? Is there a way to replace everything within two double quotes? I.E. String someString = "I want to remove this from a file plz help me, thx";

I've currently put each line of text within an ArrayList of Strings.

Here's what I've got: http://pastebin.com/N84QdLqz

Comment: It's been a while since I've done regexes, but I think the regex for a string literal, in Java, would be something along the lines of \\"[^\\"]*\\".

Comment: "Preceded by an odd number of backslashes" is actually quite painful in regex, because look behinds can't be of variable length. If you cater for up to 100 backslashes, it would require 50 separate regexes - one for each odd length of backslashes. Maybe you should refine your criteria to a reasonable limit.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've come up with a solution for your string literal regex.  Something like:

```
inputLine.replaceAll("\"([^\\\\\"]*(\\\\\")*)*([\\\\]{2})*(\\\\\")*[^\"]*\"");
```

should do the trick.  The regex is actually significantly more readable if you print it out to the console after Java has had a chance to escape all of the characters.  So if you call `System.out.println()` with that String, you'll get:

```
"([^\\"]*(\\")*)*([\\]{2})*(\\")*[^"]*"
```

I'll break down the original regex to explain.  First there's:

```
"\"([^\\\\\"]*(\\\\\")*)*
```

This says to match a quote character (`"`) followed by 0 or more patterns of characters that are neither backslashes (`\`) nor quote characters (`"`) which are followed by 0 or more escaped quotes (`\"`).  As you can see, since `\` is typically used as an escape character in Java, any regexes using them become pretty verbose.

```
([\\\\]{2})*
```

This says to next match 0 or more sets of 2 (i.e. even-numbered amounts) of backslashes.

```
(\\\\\")*
```

This says to match a single backslash followed by a quote character, and to find 0 or more of those together.

```
[^\"]*\"
```

This says to match anything that is not a quote character, 0 or more times, followed by a quote character.

I tested my regex with an example similar to what you were asking for:

> string literals (anything enclosed in double quotes, the **second** of which is not preceded by an odd number of backslashes)

Emphasis mine.  So by this statement, if the first quote in a literal has a backslash in front of it, it doesn't matter.

```
String s = "This is "a test\" + "So is this"
```

Applying the regex with `replaceAll` and a replacement of `\"\"`, you'll get:

```
String s = ""a test\""So is this"
```

which should be correct.  You can completely remove the matching literal's quotes, if you want, by calling `replaceAll` with a replacement of `""`:

```
String s = a test\So is this"
```

Alternately, using this regex on something much less contrived to cause headaches:

```
String s = "This is \"a test\\" + "So is this"
```

will return:

```
String s =  +
```

Comment: Can you maybe explain what this means? Like, what's with all the brackets and back-slashes?  I don't see any of this in the original java docs under replaceAll.  I'll give it a go, but It'd be nice to understand what's going on here so I can solve the rest of the problems.

Comment: Long story short, regexes can get ugly in Java because you first write them as Strings, and those Strings are then compiled by a pattern matching class.  If you need to match a pattern ' \x55 ', you have to escape the '\' character to make it something the regexer can parse.  Anyway, I've updated my answer with more info.

Comment: Oh, also see [the Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for the regex patterns that `replaceAll()` can match.

Comment: I just realized that I missed the part of the question about the odd number of backslashes.  I'm out of time for tonight, but I may be able to poke at this some more tomorrow.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do something like this:

```
private static final String REGEX = "(\"[\\w|\\s]*\")";
private static Pattern P;
private static Matcher M;

public static void main(String args[]){
    P = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    //.... your code here ....
 }


public static ArrayList<String> readStringsFromFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String str = new String();
        try
        {
            while(scanner.hasNext())
            {
                str = scanner.nextLine();
                str = cleanLine(str);//clean the line after read
                list.add(str);
            }
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException ex)
        {

        }
        return list;
    }

public static String cleanLine(String line) {
        int index;
        //remove comment lines
        index = line.indexOf("//");
        if (index != -1) {
            line = line.substring(0, index);
        }

        //remove everything within two double quotes
        M = P.matcher(line);
        String tmp = "";
        while(M.find()) {
            tmp = line.substring(0,M.start());
            tmp += line.substring(M.end());
            line = tmp;
            M = P.matcher(line);
        }

        return line;
    }
```